# Method to find hits in comma-separated number string on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows forms (c#) application and a table in SQL Server that has two columns like this:

```
ticket (int) | numbers (string)
12345        | '01, 02, 04, 05, 09, 10, 23'
```

This table may have like 100.000 rows or more.

Where I have to do is to found the amount of hits giving an array of numbers like a lottery.
I have 12 hits, 11 hits  and 9 hits for example and for each raffled number I have to perform the search of what win the 12 hits, 11 hits or 9 hits.

So, how is the best way to get this approach? I need the best performance.

For now I have this code:

```
string sentSQL = " SELECT ticket, numbers FROM tableA";

/* CODE TO PERFORM THE CONNECTION */
/*...*/

DbDataReader reader = connection.ExecuteReader();

int hits12, hits11, hits9 = 0;
int count;

while (reader.Read())
{
                count = 0;
                string numbers = reader["numbers"].ToString();
                string ticketNumber = reader["ticket"].ToString();
                int maxJ = balls.Count; //balls is the ArrayList with the numbers currently extracted in the raffle
                for (int j = 0; j < maxJ; j++)
                {
                    if (numbers.Contains(balls[j].ToString()))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                switch (count)
                        {
                            case 12:
                                hits12++;
                                break;
                            case 11:
                                hits11++;
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                hits9++;
                                break;
                        }
}
```

This is working but maybe there is a better method to make it possible.

I'm using SQL Server 2012, maybe is there a function that help me?

Edit: Can i perform in the sql query a `SUM` of the `CHARINDEX` of each number to get the amount of hits inside the sql query?

Comment: You should start by using a generic `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`...

Comment: Why is that? is better with List<T>?

Comment: A generic `List<T>` will not boxed integers (convert integers into objects) which causes a severe performance effect. However, the question why do you think you are having a performance problem?

Comment: Because this are Television times and we need the best performance way to get the winners.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a totally tacky solution.

```
create table ticket (
    ticketId int not null -- PK
)
create table TicketNumbers *
    ticketId int not null,
    numberSelected int not null
)
```

TicketNumbers has an FK to Ticket, and a PK of TicketNumber + numberSelected.

```
select t.ticketId, count(*) CorrectNumbers
from ticket t
inner join TicketNumbers tn on tn.ticketId = t.TicketId
where tn.numberSelected in (9, 11, 12, 15) -- list all winning numbers
group by t.ticketId
order by count(*) desc
```

Cheers -

Comment: You hope OP can update the database structure. Temporary database is not a solution since for a lottery this will run only once.

Answer (score -1):

One simple way to improve this is to update your select statement to get only records with numbers greater than your first ball number and less that your last ball number + 1 ...

Example (probably not correct SQL):

```
SELECT ticket, numbers FROM tableA where '10' < numbers and '43' > numbers
```

Comment: This would not work as the column is of type `VARCHAR` or `string`

Comment: @rae1 That is why I said it is probably bad SQL, why not go ahead and give me the correct form to update the answer?

Comment: The SQL syntax is correct. The concept is wrong. And if you do not know the *"correct form"* and need to ask for it, you should not answer in the first place.

Comment: @rae1 He was asking for an idea and I provide that. Also the concept is not wrong - that kind of comparison should work for VARCHAR or string - '01' < '20, 23, 35, 34' < '43'

Comment: First, the comparison you describe would make something like this `'01' < '20, 35, 76, 125' < '43'` to be true; second the `numbers` column contains a string of comma separated numbers: comparing against the first number of this list does not provide with proper improvement; and third, this type of string ordinal comparison involving numbers and ranges should be avoided because they do not perform a proper numerical comparison, thus `'10' < '2'`.

Comment: @rae1 First - as intended. Second - not best method, but it is an improvement over OP's code. Third - yes, but if you look at OP's sample you can notice the leading zeros. As I say before is an improvement(not the best) and it works in this case.